# WPF - Set string as asterisk (everything)

Tags: wpf

i have a rpcservice and i can query items, but now i want to query a container's name with a location on the container.
Like:
Table hase 2 location: A side = 321323 ; and B side = 321324
For now i have itemId and everything defined for my command, but it works
only if itemId is given,but on the webside if i just put * as itemId
it loads everything. With query if i set itemId as * and run the method it
want to start to find itemId with name = *

My first method was that:

```
        Command_queryItem cmd = new Command_queryItem();
        cmd.itemId = "*";
        cmd.locationInContainer = query.Text;
        res.Text = rpc.executeCommand(cmd.GetCommand, cmd.GetParameters);
```

So i made a new one:

```
        Command_queryItem cmd = new Command_queryItem();
        char[] fff = new char[0];
        fff[0] = '*';
        cmd.itemId = fff.ToString();
        cmd.locationInContainer = query.Text;
        res.Text = rpc.executeCommand(cmd.GetCommand, cmd.GetParameters);
```

But it still doesn't work. Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!